# Error in SP2016 "My Site Settings" Could not load the current My Site settings

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile-service, 2016, enterprise-search, mysite

Iam struggling to find out why I'm getting this error

> Could not load the current My Site settings

when I try to configure "my site settings". This is SP2016 On-Premise environment with single App server and single WFE server.Installed on Windows Server 2016 DataCenter. Everything is working fine, Search is crawling, and user profile service has synchronized about 500 users.

[image]

This is happening on the production environment, and I am really stressing up to fix this...

Any solution/suggestion will be appreciated...thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for the response.
I have done almost every thing explained en tehnet article how to configure mysite, but still iam not able to configure "My Site settings"...?

- My Site host site collection, Is created
- Wildcard inclusion added Managed Path, configured
- enable Self-service site collection, enabled

Comment: By deleten all services, and re creating all services again helped me to solve to issue....

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure you have configured a My Site host site collection and wildcard inclusion managed path configured for My Sites, enable self-service site creation for the web application before update the My site settings.

Reference: [Configure My Sites in SharePoint Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624362(v=office.16).aspx)

Then make sure the farm account have full control permission to the search service application.